# Formula for Supernetting the multiple blocks of IPv6 pools

Tags: ipv6, subnet

Can you pl guide me how i can calculate the Supernet from multiple blocks of IPv6 pools ?

For e.g. -

How to calculate the supernet pool of the following IPv6 blocks -

2407:9580::/32 2407:a2c0::/32 2407:a6c0::/32 2407:a800::/32 2407:b0c0::/32 2407:bc40::/32 2407:c800::/32 2407:d440::/32 2407:d600::/32 2407:d800::/32 2407:e600::/32 2407:f600::/32 2408::/22 2409:10::/28 2409:250::/28 240a::/25 240b::/26 240b:240::/26 240d::/27 240f::/24 240f:100::/24

Comment: Convert the addresses to 128-bit binary values (what an IPv6 address really is). Compare the values, starting with the high order bit count the number of consecutive bits that match in all the addresses. That will be the prefix length, and the consecutive matching bits with enough `0` bits to make 128 will be the prefix, and you convert that back to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert those addresses to 128-bit unsigned integers
2. exclusive-or first two addresses, all equal bits resulting in zeros
3. count the zero (=same) bits from the beginning
4. the lesser of any previous prefix length and your current count is your new prefix length
5. take either start address (from step 2) and mask all bits other than the prefix to zero
6. repeat with next address

Note that the result is the smallest supernet that contains all listed subnets - it can very well contain ranges that were *not* part of the listed subnets.